# Why does this jquery-Script work? (concerning drop down list on hover)

Tags: jquery, html, events, drop-down-menu, mouseleave

I am trying to figure out why this jquery script works perfectly fine.

this is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="hover.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Parent 01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="selected">Parent 02</a>
                <ul id="dropdown" style="display: none;">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="selected">Item 02</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 03</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 03</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 04</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 05</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 06</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 07</a></li>
            </ul>           
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 04</a></li>
         </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see just a simple menu. Now i use css to hide the submenus with display:none;.

And the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        alert('enter');
        $('#dropdown', this).show();

    }, 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        alert('leave');
        $('#dropdown', this).hide();
    }
);

});
```

Now what I dont get is: Why, when I leave "Parent 02" with my mouse (hovering over to a submenu item), it wont immediately fire the "mouseleave" event but will wait until the events of the subnav are processed. I can only assume that it has to deal with the event queue.

Live Demo: http://paugasolin.funpic.de/test.html

Comment: Maybe because the sub-elements are sub-elements of the hover you're looking at?

Comment: yeah, the hover inherits all subitems. thats the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not close immediately because the elements are sub-elements of the thing you are hovering over. Because of this, it considers you to still be hovering over that area as you *are* hovering over the area.

Comment: ok, so now that you have answered, shall i still update my answer?

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
$('#nav li').hover(function() {
    //show its submenu
    alert('enter');
    $(this).children('#dropdown').show();

});
```

Comment: You haven't answered the question though. He was asking why, not for code.